# Why does git pull find conflict on file moved as deleted in HEAD?

Tags: git

I moved a folder in my GitHub fork with `git mv`, all files are updated correctly on pull from upstream when I do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/atiertant/offshore.git
cd offshore/
git remote add waterline balderdashy/waterline
git pull waterline master
```

Except one: Git say `lib/waterline/query/deferred.js` is deleted in `HEAD` but I moved it to `lib/offshore/query/deferred.js`.

I tried:

```
git fetch waterline master:waterline
git checkout waterline
git mv lib/waterline lib/offshore
git commit
git checkout master
git merge waterline
```

But my file `lib/offshore/deffered.js` is replaced by waterline version

What can I do to relink those two files to have all changes of waterline with my changes?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is or what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you clarify your question, perhaps by telling us in a few sentences what you are trying to do?

Comment: Have you moved file with mv or with git mv?

Comment: What do you mean by "file `lib/offshore/deffered.js` is completely overwritten"?

Comment: @CodeWizard yes, i moved the folder lib/waterline to lib/offshore using: `git mv lib/waterline lib/offshore`

@TimBiegeleisen i try to get changes in waterline to my code,all changes are applyed correctly except this file now

@alextercete i mean only waterline version persist, i haven't got my changes in final file